# winSCP not listing directory problem

Tags: ftp, winscp

I'm trying to use winSCP to FTP my server using FTPs and then synch with a backup folder. I have had this working fine from a PC on my work intranet (i.e. the same domain) however when I try to set it up off site (which is my whole point) the same script fails. The FTP log is as follows..

```
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 WinSCP Version 4.2.8 (Build 818) (OS 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2)
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 Login time: 09 September 2010 15:28:30
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 Session name: user1@myserver.nhs.uk
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 Host name: myserver.nhs.uk (Port: 21)
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 User name: user1 (Password: Yes, Key file: No)
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 Tunnel: No
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 Transfer Protocol: FTP
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 Ping type: C, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 Proxy: none
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 FTP: FTPS: Explicit SSL; Passive: No [Force IP: No]
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: No, Cache: Yes
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 DST mode: 1
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.952 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.968 Connecting to myserver.nhs.uk ...
. 2010-09-09 15:28:30.984 Connected with myserver.nhs.uk, negotiating SSL connection...
< 2010-09-09 15:28:30.999 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 2010-09-09 15:28:30.999 AUTH SSL
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.031 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:31.187 SSL connection established. Waiting for welcome message...
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.187 USER user1
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.218 331 Password required for user1.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.218 PASS ********
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.234 230 User logged in.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.234 SYST
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.265 215 Windows_NT
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.265 FEAT
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.281 211-Extended features supported:
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.281  LANG EN*
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.281  UTF8
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.281  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.281  PBSZ
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.281  PROT C;P;
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.281  CCC
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.296  HOST
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.296  SIZE
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.296  MDTM
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.296  REST STREAM
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.296 211 END
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.296 OPTS UTF8 ON
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.312 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.312 PBSZ 0
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.343 200 PBSZ command successful.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.343 PROT P
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.359 200 PROT command successful.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:31.359 Connected
. 2010-09-09 15:28:31.359 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2010-09-09 15:28:31.359 Using FTP protocol.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:31.359 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.359 PWD
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.390 257 "/" is current directory.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:31.390 Getting current directory name.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:31.390 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.390 TYPE A
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.406 200 Type set to A.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.421 PORT 10,222,54,3,6,38
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.437 200 PORT command successful.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:31.437 LIST -a
< 2010-09-09 15:28:31.468 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:46.968 Timeout detected.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:46.968 Could not retrieve directory listing
* 2010-09-09 15:28:46.968 (ESshFatal) Lost connection.
* 2010-09-09 15:28:46.968 Timeout detected.
* 2010-09-09 15:28:46.968 Could not retrieve directory listing
* 2010-09-09 15:28:46.968 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
* 2010-09-09 15:28:46.968 Error listing directory '/'.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:51.999 Connecting to myserver.nhs.uk ...
. 2010-09-09 15:28:52.015 Connected with myserver.nhs.uk, negotiating SSL connection...
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.031 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.031 AUTH SSL
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.062 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:52.140 SSL connection established. Waiting for welcome message...
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.140 USER user1
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.156 331 Password required for user1.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.156 PASS ********
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.187 230 User logged in.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.187 SYST
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.202 215 Windows_NT
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.202 FEAT
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234 211-Extended features supported:
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  LANG EN*
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  UTF8
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  PBSZ
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  PROT C;P;
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  CCC
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  HOST
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  SIZE
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  MDTM
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234  REST STREAM
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234 211 END
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.234 OPTS UTF8 ON
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.265 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.265 PBSZ 0
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.281 200 PBSZ command successful.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.281 PROT P
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.312 200 PROT command successful.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:52.312 Connected
. 2010-09-09 15:28:52.312 Doing startup conversation with host.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:52.312 Getting current directory name.
. 2010-09-09 15:28:52.312 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.312 PWD
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.343 257 "/" is current directory.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.343 TYPE A
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.359 200 Type set to A.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.359 PORT 10,222,54,3,6,40
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.390 200 PORT command successful.
> 2010-09-09 15:28:52.390 LIST -a
< 2010-09-09 15:28:52.406 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
```

This fails whether I run from GUI or a previously tested and working scripted version. It looks from the log like theres a problem with a timeout on the directory listing, presumably it works locally as less lag

Any ideas if this is a winSCP setting (and if so where) or on the FTPserver side (Windows Web Server 2008 R2) ?

Comment: Sorry about the imnage file, the log unformats to a wall of text, even if wrapped in a pre tag :-(

Comment: I formatted it in a code block

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem when I forgot to open the extra ports that Passive FTP mode requires.

Basically, you need to open/allow a range of ports through your firewall in addition port 21 that you have already opened.

It looks like you are using Microsoft's FTP Server.  Microsoft has a support page with instructions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=555022).

When I did this, I opened port 21 for the control port, and then arbitrarily chose ports 65000-65050 for the Passive FTP Data. Your range will vary based on the number of concurrent users/sessions you need or expect (more concurrent users/sessions require more open ports) and any other ports that are already open for other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this myself. Many pages have the same question, but often not the (full) answer.
It's the PASV ports that need to be reachable in PASV mode.
This may need the firewall/IPtables to be adjusted:

[How to configure vsftpd to work with passive mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/421161/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-work-with-passive-mode)

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Instead of providing a link to the solution, please state at least the essentials of it here, so your answer will still be useful if the linked page goes away.