# How to configure vsftpd to work with passive mode

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

Whenever I install `vsftpd` on `centos`, I only setup the jail environment for the users and rest is default configuration of `vsftpd`. I create user and try to connect with `filezila` ftp client, but I could not connect with passive mode. I always change the `transfer settings` to active mode to successfully connect to the `ftp server` otherwise I get

```
 Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

So is there a way to change any directive in `vsftp.conf` file and we can connect with passive mode to the server?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To configure passive mode for vsftpd you need to set some parameters in vsftpd.conf.

```
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_max_port=10100
pasv_min_port=10090
```

This enables passive mode and restricts it to using the eleven ports for data connections. This is useful as you need to open these ports on your firewall.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 10090:10100 -j ACCEPT
```

If after testing this all works then save the state of your firewall with

```
service iptables save
```

which will update the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file.

To do this is CentOS 7 you have to use the new firewalld, not iptables:

Find your zone:

```
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: eth0
```

My zone is 'public', so I set my zone to public, add the port range, and after that we reload:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=10090-10100/tcp
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

What happens when you make a connection

- Your client makes a connection to the vsftpd server on port 21.
- The sever responds to the client telling it which port to connect to from the range specified above.
- The client makes a data connection on the specified port and the session continues.

There is a great explanation of the different ftp [modes](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) here.

Comment: Wondering why you put the `max` port after the `min`... but more importantly, if you open ports 10090 to 10100, that's 11 ports and not 10 as you say.

Comment: I believe it's alphabetical, it really doesn't matter as they are separate directives.

Comment: This is not working for me without `pasv_address`.

Comment: took me ages to find this, none of the vsftpd guides list this... brilliant

Comment: Wonderful - this vsftp configuration solved all my FTP-firewall problems :)

Comment: `pasv_enable=YES` is default btw, not required in the config file

Answer (score 29):

To enable passive mode, set the following configuration options in your vsftp.conf:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=41361
pasv_max_port=65534
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

You can of course change the start and end port, and should replace the xxx's with the public IP of your server.

In addition, you should open the passive mode port range in your firewall. On centos, you can load the `ip_conntrack_ftp` module to handle ftp connections in your firewall. Edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` and add ip_conntrack_ftp to the IPTABLES_MODULES option. Afterwards restart iptables:

```
/sbin/service iptables restart
```

Comment: `pasv_address` is what does the trick when everything else has been set up and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @fbmd before trying pasv_address, one should also check if both pasv_max and min_port are in the right order. It happened to me that I had the max value configured in the pasv_min_port, and vsftpd simply ignores this. It is a known silent flaw / bug that will visually makes you think that pasv ports are correclty configured, but they are not. This happened to me, and solved my problem.

Comment: If you want to specify a DNS address in `pasv_address`, you should add `pasv_addr_resolve=YES` (defaults to `NO`)

Comment: `pasv_address` is required to be set to external IP address when FTP server is behind router with ports forwarded. Also the router need to have hairpin NAT option enabled to have FTP accessible locally.

Answer (score 8):

Beside the `pasv_enable=YES`, specify a port range in which VSFTP will run PASV mode:

```
pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_max_port=50999
pasv_enable=YES
```

Don't forget to configure iptables allows packet transmission on these ports:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 50000:50999 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: On a standard CentOS system there is a blanket DROP that causes rules added with `iptables -A INPUT ... ` to be ignored

Comment: Make sure you include `pasv_address` in the vsftpd.conf file.

Answer (score 6):

I had to do the following steps to get vsftp passive mode working on CentOS 8:

Enable passive mode in vsftpd config `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.config`:

```
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_max_port=50999
```

Enable ftp Service in firewalld:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=ftp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

As mentioned in another [post](https://serverfault.com/a/880552) you have to load the kernel module "nf_conntrack_ftp" (which was already the case in CentOS 8) **and enable "nf_conntrack_helper" in kernel settings**:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper
```

Add this line to `/etc/sysctl.conf` (or `/etc/sysctl.d/10-nf_conntrack_helper.conf` when `/etc/sysctl.d/` is present) for a reboot persistent setting:

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper=1
```

With connection track enabled there is no need to additional configure the passive ports in the local firewall.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, it's not the ftp server, vsftpd, but the firewall like iptable that prevents passive mode from being used (blocking tcp connection needed for data transfert).

Comment: Actually, vsftpd could be smart enough to open a port in the firewall... but from the answers I see here, it does not look like it's capable of such a feat.

Comment: @Alexsis. There is no point to a firewall if apps just ignore the rules and open ports anyway.