# Allowing passive FTP connections in FirewallD (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, ftp, firewalld

In CentOS 7 which comes with FirewallD, enabling HTTP access was easy:

```bash
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
```

However,

```bash
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=ftp
```

doesn't work: the rule applies, but I can't access FTP by any means except disabling FirewallD.

Some diagnostic info:

- I have checked the service definition file (ftp.xml) and it makes use of nf_conntrack_ftp module.
- On my VPS the module is compiled into kernel (not separate) so it's not there via lsmod, but I can confirm it's there by this:

```
zgrep FTP /proc/config.gz
```

```
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_TFTP=y
```

Comment: This will more likely than not be the usual problem will passive more http://serverfault.com/questions/421161/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-work-with-passive-mode/421169#421169

Comment: Solution for CentOS 8: https://serverfault.com/a/995047/298522

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure vsftpd to work with passive mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/421161/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-work-with-passive-mode)

Comment: Both answers here are bad, they do not rely on intelligent connection tracking made possible by `nf_conntrack_helper`.

Answer (score 8):

I did not researched the issue throughly, so I do not understand the details, but it seems this has something to do with how the active - passive connections are setup both for vsftpd on the server and for the client (ex: Filezilla).

Basically you will need to:

- configure vsfptd passive mode by adding the following to /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf:

  `pasv_enable=Yes
  pasv_max_port=40000
  pasv_min_port=40000`
- Restart vsftpd:

  `systemctl restart vsftpd.service`
- Ope port 4000 in FirewallD:

  `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=40000/tcp
  firewall-cmd --reload`
- Then I was able to connect with `lftp`. For setting Filezilla to use active mode check http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/enable-passive-mode-in-ftp-on-centos-7-rhel-7-for-filezilla-and-winscp.html#axzz3X4loTCMi

Answer (score 1):

try:
edit `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=65400
pasv_max_port=65410
```

Then:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 1 -p TCP --dport 21 --sport 1024:65534 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 1 -p TCP --dport 65400:65410 --sport 1024:65534 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --get-all-rules
```

I use vsftp server & FileZilla Client can working