# Passive mode for vsftpd from Windows command-line FTP client

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-14.04, vsftpd

I have tried configuring vsftpd to work in passive mode, however, with no success. I have followed the instructions given in the answer for question [How to configure vsftpd to work with passive mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/421161/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-work-with-passive-mode) and I have also followed [this article](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/) where they explain how exactly to set up vsftpd and I did it on a clean installation of Ubuntu Server 14.04.3.

My `iptables` looks like this after invoking `iptables --list`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:40000:40100
```

I have tried restarting the vsftpd service and I have also restarted the server but no change.

I am able to login and browse/edit the files from the browser as well as in Windows Explorer, but when I try to connect to the server using `ftp` command using Windows command line, I log in and after issuing a command (such as `ls`), it says

> 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.

and gets stuck there (because I have not enabled anything in the firewall so that's ok).

Is there any reason why my vsftpd is not behaving as in passive mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows command-line FTP client does not support the passive mode. You cannot fix it by any server-side configuration.

If you need a scriptable Windows FTP client with a passive mode support, you have to use a different one.

---

For example *my* WinSCP FTP client [supports scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) and defaults to a passive mode.

There's a guide available for [converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, WinSCP in fact behaves exactly as I would expect and want. I somehow assumed that the Windows FTP client would work and so I was trying to find the problem in the server configuration. Thanks again.